# woocommerce_quantity_input appears twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with
woocommerce_quantity. Everything works fine now, but woocommerce_quantity appears twice in the frontend. I have already searched various sites and have not yet found a solution to the problem.

Here is my code:

```
if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $current_lang = pll_current_language();
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ); <-- Here is the quantity i needed.
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="lightbox_for_products" value="1">';
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
        $html .= '<div id="ts_shop_modal_products" class="modal">';
        $html .= '<div class="modal-content">';
        $html .= '<span class="close">&times;</span>';
            if ( $current_lang == 'de' ) {
                $html .= '<button class="button alt"><a style="color: #fff" href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '">'. pll__( 'Zum Warenkorb' ) .'</a></button><br/><br/>';
                $html .= '<button class="button alt"><a style="color: #fff" href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'/eintrittskartenshop/" >' . pll__( 'Zurück zur Übersicht' ) . '</a></button>';
            } else {
                                $html .= '<button class="button alt"><a style="color: #fff" href="' . wc_get_cart_url() . '">'. pll__( 'Zum Warenkorb' ) .'</a></button><br/><br/>';
                                $html .= '<button class="button alt"><a style="color: #fff" href="'. get_bloginfo('url') .'/en/shop" >' . pll__( 'Zurück zur Übersicht' ) . '</a></button>';
            }
            $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
```

In frontend it looks like this:

[image: Frontend]

Comment: Have you remove the previous `woommerce_quanity_input` call from the standard Woocommerce templates?

Comment: @JoshBonnick 

No I did not. But good advice. One question, however: Will this data be overwritten with the next WooCommerce update? Or do I have to put this template file into my theme and then edit it?

Comment: @JoshBonnick 
If so, which template do I need for this?

Comment: Yes it will be overwritten by the next update. You need to add all of your theme modifications into your theme. `templates/single-product/add-to-cart/` inside there you have product types, you'll most likely need single though

Comment: @JoshBonnick Ah okay many thanks for this info. But which template do i need?

Comment: single.php is for standard products so probably that one. If you want to change variation products then you will need the variation.php template